# Python -- Dictionary comprehension inside an OrderedDict not working

Tags: python, for-loop, typeerror, ordereddictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have this code:

```
self.statusIcons = collections.OrderedDict
for index in guiConfig.STATUS_ICON_SETS:
     self.statusIcons[index] = {condition:\
           wx.Image(guiConfig.STATUS_ICON_STRING.format(index, condition),wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap() \
           for condition in guiConfig.STATUS_ICON_CONDITIONS}
```

It sets up an ordereddict of regular dictionaries of wx.Image objects which are set up with comprehension.  I originally had nested dict comprehensions and it worked fine but decided I needed the top-level dict to be ordered so ended up with this way.  The problem is that now I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment
```

zeroing in on the piece of the code in question.  I can't figure out what I did incorrectly.  Does ordereddict not allow comprehension even if it isn't the top-level?  Maybe it tries to order all dicts within an ordereddict and can't because comprehension is on the lower-level?  Not sure, maybe it's something ridiculous I couldn't spot because of tunnel-vision.

PS: in case you need to know what is in the globals I reference above:

```
STATUS_ICON_SETS = ("comp", "net", "serv", "audio", "sec", "ups", "zwave", "stats")
STATUS_ICON_CONDITIONS = ("on", "off")
STATUS_ICON_STRING = "images/{0}_{1}.png"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **call** the type to create an instance:

```
self.statusIcons = collections.OrderedDict()
```

You omitted the `()` there.

You can create the OrderedDict elements in a generator expression producing `(key, value)` tuples here too:

```
self.statusIcons = collections.OrderedDict(
    (index, {condition: wx.Image(
                 guiConfig.STATUS_ICON_STRING.format(index, condition),
                 wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap()
             for condition in guiConfig.STATUS_ICON_CONDITIONS})
    for index in guiConfig.STATUS_ICON_SETS)
```

but I am not sure readability has improved with that approach.

Comment: Very quick answer, thank you.  And it worked ;)  Now I feel silly.  I thought about assigning it with arguments but the comments in the ordereddict source said not to do that, I guess because argument order can get mixed up?  Not sure.  I'll try that and test and make sure it stays in order.  Thanks.